# How to count the number of missing values in each row of a data frame -spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to count the number of missing values in each row of a data frame in spark scala.

Code:

```
val samplesqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sampletable")

samplesqlDF.show()
```

Input Dataframe:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
   | name       |     age             |  degree    | Place            |
   | -----------------------------------------------------------------|
   | Ram        |                     |    MCA     | Bangalore        |
   |            |     25              |            |                  |
   |            |     26              |     BE     |                  |
   | Raju       |     21              |     Btech  |  Chennai         |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Output Data frame (Row Level Count) as follows:

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
   | name       |     age   |  degree    | Place      |   rowcount   |
   | ----------------------------------------------------------------|
   | Ram        |           |    MCA     | Bangalore  |   1          |
   |            |     25    |            |            |   3          |
   |            |     26    |     BE     |            |   2          |
   | Raju       |     21    |    Btech   |  Chennai   |   0          | 
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am a beginner to scala and spark. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You may take a look to [this link - how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this a future questions. Specially, you should provide some research effort and/or some code to probe you already tried to solve your problem by yourself.

Comment: Hi, how about looking at the solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like  you want to get the null count in a dynamic way. Check this out

```
val df = Seq(("Ram",null,"MCA","Bangalore"),(null,"25",null,null),(null,"26","BE",null),("Raju","21","Btech","Chennai")).toDF("name","age","degree","Place")
df.show(false)
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)( (df,c) => df.withColumn(c+"_null", when(col(c).isNull,1).otherwise(0) ) )
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("student")
val sql_str_null = df.columns.map( x => x+"_null").mkString(" ","+"," as null_count ")
val sql_str_full = df.columns.mkString( "select ", ",", " , " + sql_str_null + " from student")
spark.sql(sql_str_full).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
|name|age |degree|Place    |null_count|
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
|Ram |null|MCA   |Bangalore|1         |
|null|25  |null  |null     |3         |
|null|26  |BE    |null     |2         |
|Raju|21  |Btech |Chennai  |0         |
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a possibility and checking also for "" but not using foldLeft just to demonstrate the point:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(("Ram",null,"MCA","Bangalore"),(null,"25",null,""),(null,"26","BE",null),("Raju","21","Btech","Chennai")).toDF("name","age","degree","place")

// Count per row the null or "" columns! 
val null_counter = Seq("name", "age", "degree", "place").map(x => when(col(x) === "" || col(x).isNull , 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _)  

val df2 = df.withColumn("nulls_cnt", null_counter)

df2.show(false)
```

returns:

```
 +----+----+------+---------+---------+
 |name|age |degree|place    |nulls_cnt|
 +----+----+------+---------+---------+
 |Ram |null|MCA   |Bangalore|1        |
 |null|25  |null  |         |3        |
 |null|26  |BE    |null     |2        |
 |Raju|21  |Btech |Chennai  |0        |
 +----+----+------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: You can also translate the tanks into an upvote as a sign of appreciation, and, it points out to others then that it is a valid option ...

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of the one suggested by @stack0114106 is

```
val df = Seq(("Ram",null,"MCA","Bangalore"),(null,"25",null,null), 
             (null,"26","BE",null),("Raju","21","Btech","Chennai"))
        .toDF("name","age","degree","Place")
        .withColumn("null_count", lit(0))

val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df,c) => 
            df.withColumn("null_count", 
                when(col(c).isNull,$"null_count" + 1).otherwise($"null_count")
            )
        )
df2.show(false)
```

the output is

```
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
|name|age |degree|Place    |null_count|
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
|Ram |null|MCA   |Bangalore|1         |
|null|25  |null  |null     |3         |
|null|26  |BE    |null     |2         |
|Raju|21  |Btech |Chennai  |0         |
+----+----+------+---------+----------+
```